# Is there an updated version of the Java Code Conventions

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions, code-conversion

The official Java Code Conventions document -that I could get hold of- is dated 1997 and it seems that Oracle has no updated version of it.

Oracle actually states on the conventions page that:

> The information on this page is for Archive Purposes Only
>
> This page is not being actively maintained. Links within the
>   documentation may not work and the information itself may no longer be
>   valid. The last revision to this document was made on April 20, 1999

**Is there an official or at least a de facto official conventions that are more recent?**

Note: I'm not asking here about a good or the best convention, I'm asking about **the** updated standard or **the** de facto standard if any. So, an answer should not be an opinion-based one.

Comment: The most widely used de facto convention is called "Eclipse default formatting settings" :)

Comment: Code Conventions seem to be written in stone :(

Comment: google's seems as good as anything: http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: @biziclop the eclipse formatting settings does not include many important aspects of the Java convention; like classes and methods naming, braces placement, blank lines...

Comment: @AhmadY.Saleh It does include braces placement, but mainly it was just a joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an official or at least a de facto official conventions that are more recent?

No there isn't a more recent official Sun / Oracle version of the Guidelines.  (Or if there is, it is internal to Sun / Oracle.)

There are other more recent Java style guides around (Google is your friend!) but nothing that I would call a "defacto standard".